# É possível referenciar uma coluna que não seja chave primária em outra tabela?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Por exemplo, eu quero referenciar o id_2 da Tabela 1 na Tabela 2, eu sei que dá para fazer com chaves primárias mas com outras colunas eu não sei se é possível.

Tabela 1: 
id (chave primária da tabela 1),
id_2,
nome

Tabela 2:
id_tabela2 (chave primária da tabela 2),
id_2 (da tabela 1),
nome

Comment: Por que estão negativando?

Comment: Só uma suposição @Andrey, talvez haja colegas que infelizmente pensem que uma pergunta básica não mereça reconhecimento, mesmo que seja uma tão comum. É possível referenciar praticamente qualquer coluna (não blob), mesmo que não seja única! Porém se você está referenciando um ID que não é PK revise seu schema, se vc está referenciando uma que não é nem mesmo única revise três vezes e chame colegas para um segunda opnião. Sugestão: Não esqueça de cobrir a coluna referenciada com um index, caso já não exista um

Answer (score 4):

Isto pode se tornar uma [chave](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_candidata) [candidata](http://www.luis.blog.br/chave%20primaria-chave-estrangeira-e-candidata.aspx), mas chave primária não.

> **Chaves candidata**
>
> Ocorrem quando em uma relação existe mais de uma combinação de atributos possuindo a propriedade de identificação única. A chave candidata é apenas conceitual, ou seja, ela não é implementada. O que acontece é que os atributos com essa características poderiam ser primária já que possuem por natureza a identificação única.
>
> Alguns exemplos: Matrícula, CPF, RG, Titulo Eleitor, entre outros.
>
> **Fonte:** segundo link.

Comment: A sua resposta foi muito útil Andrey. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma chave única ([Unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)) no campo **id_2** da **tabela 1**. Isso além de garantir a integridade da sua chave, também permite a referência para ela.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando um cenário aonde:

> Tabela1: id (chave primária da tabela 1), id_2, nome, CATEGORIA (novo
>   campo)
>
> Tabela2: id_tabela2 (chave primária da tabela 2), id_2 (da tabela 1),
>   nome, CATEGORIA (novo campo)

Uma consulta nestas duas tabelas utilizando a categoria para comparação ficaria assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabela1 T1, Tabela2 T2
WHERE T1.id_2 = T2.id_2
AND T1.CATEGORIA = T2.CATEGORIA
```

Você tem sempre que tratar as relações entre chaves primárias e estrangeiras em uma consulta SQL.

Mas, se você retirar a chave estrangeira ficaria desse jeito:

> Tabela1: id (chave primária da tabela 1), id_2, nome, CATEGORIA (novo
>   campo)
>
> Tabela2: id_tabela2 (chave primária da tabela 2), nome, CATEGORIA
>   (novo campo)

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabela1 T1, Tabela2 T2
WHERE T1.CATEGORIA = T2.CATEGORIA
```

Só lembrando que se os campos permitirem valores nulos sua consulta mudaria.
Mas acho que deu pra entender.

Abs.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, mas caso o seu id_2 for nulo ou obter itens em duplicidade, você pode ter um relacionamento N-N, caso ela não tenha o atributo UNIQUE, que impede sua duplicidade e inserção de nulos, você acabar tendo um banco não normalizado.

Caso você necessite relacionar duas tabelas onde possa haver relacionamento de muitos para muitos (não sei se é este o seu caso) você pode utilizar uma tabela auxiliar para este relacionamento, e nesta nova tabela você pode utilizar as duas colunas como chave primária e nem precisaria referenciar a coluna id_2 na tabela 1.

Consulte algumas referências sobre normalização de banco que podem lhe esclarecer sobre este assunto. Caso não necessite deste rigor, especialmente em tabelas extremamente grandes, necessitando maior performance de banco, a resposta de pdonatilio poder ser sua solução